# AVfoundation unable to record audio in iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder, ios5

I'm having some major trouble trying to get a simple audio recording function built and I'm not sure why. I've followed some code (from here and other places) to build a very simple audio recorder and playback, but nothing works. Ive taken sample code that works from iOS 4.3 and that works fine when i run it by itself, but as soon as I bring it up to iOS 5 and use ARC, nothing happens.  The app runs, but no audio is recorded… any ideas would be great!  thanks… attached all my code. This is code from a sample here.

record_audio_testViewController.h

```
 #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <CoreAudio/CoreAudioTypes.h>

@interface record_audio_testViewController : UIViewController <AVAudioRecorderDelegate> {

    IBOutlet UIButton * btnStart;
    IBOutlet UIButton * btnPlay;
    IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView * actSpinner;
    BOOL toggle;

    //Variables setup for access in the class:
    NSURL * recordedTmpFile;
    AVAudioRecorder * recorder;
    NSError *__autoreleasing * error;
    AVAudioSession * audioSession;

}

@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIActivityIndicatorView * actSpinner;
@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton * btnStart;
@property (nonatomic,retain)IBOutlet UIButton * btnPlay;
@property (nonatomic,strong)    AVAudioSession * audioSession;
@property (nonatomic,strong)    AVAudioRecorder * recorder;

- (IBAction) start_button_pressed;
- (IBAction) play_button_pressed;
@end
```

record_audio_testViewController.m

```
#import "record_audio_testViewController.h"


@implementation record_audio_testViewController
@synthesize actSpinner, btnStart, btnPlay, audioSession, recorder;



/*
// The designated initializer. Override to perform setup that is required before the view is loaded.
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    if (self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil]) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}
*/

/*
// Implement loadView to create a view hierarchy programmatically, without using a nib.
- (void)loadView {
}
*/



// Implement viewDidLoad to do additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //Start the toggle in true mode.
    toggle = YES;
    btnPlay.hidden = YES;

    //Instanciate an instance of the AVAudioSession object.
    audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    //Setup the audioSession for playback and record. 
    //We could just use record and then switch it to playback leter, but
    //since we are going to do both lets set it up once.
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: error];
    //Activate the session
    [audioSession setActive:YES error: error];
    NSLog(@"%@",error);

}



/*
// Override to allow orientations other than the default portrait orientation.
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
*/

- (IBAction)  start_button_pressed{

    if(toggle)
    {
        toggle = NO;
        [actSpinner startAnimating];
        [btnStart setTitle:@"Stop Recording" forState: UIControlStateNormal ];  
        btnPlay.enabled = toggle;
        btnPlay.hidden = !toggle;

        //Begin the recording session.
        //Error handling removed.  Please add to your own code.

        //Setup the dictionary object with all the recording settings that this 
        //Recording sessoin will use
        //Its not clear to me which of these are required and which are the bare minimum.
        //This is a good resource: http://www.totodotnet.net/tag/avaudiorecorder/
        NSMutableDictionary* recordSetting = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        [recordSetting setValue :[NSNumber numberWithInt:kAudioFormatAppleIMA4] forKey:AVFormatIDKey];
        [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:44100.0] forKey:AVSampleRateKey]; 
        [recordSetting setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt: 2] forKey:AVNumberOfChannelsKey];

        //Now that we have our settings we are going to instanciate an instance of our recorder instance.
        //Generate a temp file for use by the recording.
        //This sample was one I found online and seems to be a good choice for making a tmp file that
        //will not overwrite an existing one.
        //I know this is a mess of collapsed things into 1 call.  I can break it out if need be.
        recordedTmpFile = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent: [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%.0f.%@", [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] * 1000.0, @"caf"]]];
        NSLog(@"Using File called: %@",recordedTmpFile);
        //Setup the recorder to use this file and record to it.
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
        recorder = [[ AVAudioRecorder alloc] initWithURL:recordedTmpFile settings:recordSetting error:error];
        NSLog(@"%@",error);
        //Use the recorder to start the recording.
        //Im not sure why we set the delegate to self yet.  
        //Found this in antother example, but Im fuzzy on this still.
        [recorder setDelegate:self];
        //We call this to start the recording process and initialize 
        //the subsstems so that when we actually say "record" it starts right away.
        [recorder prepareToRecord];
        //Start the actual Recording
        [recorder record];
        //There is an optional method for doing the recording for a limited time see 
        //[recorder recordForDuration:(NSTimeInterval) 10]

    }
    else
    {
        toggle = YES;
        [actSpinner stopAnimating];
        [btnStart setTitle:@"Start Recording" forState:UIControlStateNormal ];
        btnPlay.enabled = toggle;
        btnPlay.hidden = !toggle;

        NSLog(@"Using File called: %@",recordedTmpFile);
        //Stop the recorder.
        [recorder stop];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    // Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

-(IBAction) play_button_pressed{

    //The play button was pressed... 
    //Setup the AVAudioPlayer to play the file that we just recorded.

    AVAudioPlayer * avPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:recordedTmpFile error:error];
    [avPlayer prepareToPlay];
    [avPlayer play];
     NSLog(@"%@",error);

}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
    //Clean up the temp file.
    NSFileManager * fm = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    [fm removeItemAtPath:[recordedTmpFile path] error:error];
    //Call the dealloc on the remaining objects.

}



@end
```

viewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "record_audio_testViewController.h"


@interface ViewController : UIViewController{
record_audio_testViewController *audioControl;

}

@end
```

viewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "record_audio_testViewController.h"


@implementation ViewController


- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];
    audioControl = [[record_audio_testViewController alloc] init];
    [self.view addSubview:audioControl.view];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

Comment: you should at least have an idea where there is a problem. You can't just post all of your code and tell other people to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

(1) This may have nothing to do with your question, but I am amazed that this even compiles:

```
NSError *__autoreleasing * error; // ivar
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: error];
```

That's no way to talk. `error` should be a local variable and you should be taking its address, and you have no business tagging it as autoreleasing:

```
NSError *error;
[audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error: &error];
```

(2) Don't use PlayAndRecord unless you are something like a VoIP app. If what you want to do is record, your audio session policy should be Record, and only while you are actually recording.

I'm sorry if neither of those solves the problem but they are probably things you should get out of the way first.